# How to check if elements in list 'a' meet conditions in list 'b'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of **numbers**:

```
a = [3, 6, 20, 24, 36, 92, 130]
```

And a list of **conditions**:

```
b = ["2", "5", "20", "range(50,100)", ">120"]
```

I want to check if a number in 'a' meets one of the conditions in 'b' and if yes, put these numbers in list 'c'

In above case:

```
c = [20, 92, 130]
```

I created this code what seems to do what I want:

```
c = []
for x in a:
    for y in b:
        if "range" in y:
            rangelist = list(eval(y))
            if x in rangelist:
                c.append(x)
        elif ">" in y or "<" in y:
            if eval(str(x) + y):
                c.append(x)
        else:
            if x == eval(y):
                c.append(x)
```

However my list 'a' can be very big.
Is there not an easier and faster way to obtain what I want?

Comment: why are you saving string in the conditions and not integers, that would make things easier.

Comment: Can you change `b` to be valid condition like `=20` or `in range(50,100)`?

Comment: It seems a lot cleaner to put functions in your `b` list instead of doing a bunch of janky string manipulation and `eval`.

Comment: Furthermore if you are considerate about the performance, depending on the input values you want to run the checks in a specific order to short-circuit.

Comment: @Mureinik, yes it is possible or maybe also using list comprehensions

Comment: @user2357112 functions in b?

Comment: Stuff like `lambda x: x > 120` or `lambda x: 50 <= x < 100`.

Comment: If your list a is very big, you might consider splitting it up and having multiple threads doing it. Or even celery it to other machines.

Comment: This was a fun exercise in Haskell, since it involved defining a reverse-map (which is something that's probably in Haskell stdlib but I couldn't find it) of type `a -> [(a -> b)] -> [b]`. [See my solution here](https://repl.it/repls/QuizzicalMonstrousTurnstone)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Building on @user2357112's suggestion, you can create a list of functions for all your conditions, then pass each number, to each function to determine whether the number meets any of the conditions, or not.

```
In [1]: a = [3, 6, 20, 24, 36, 92, 130]

In [2]: conditions = [lambda x:x==2, lambda x:x==5, lambda x:x==20, lambda x: x in range(50, 100), lambda x: x > 120]  # List of lambda functions

In [3]: output = list()

In [4]: for number in a:
   ...:     if any(func(number) for func in conditions): # Check if the number satisfies any of the given conditions by passing the number as an argument to each function
   ...:         output.append(number)         

In [5]: output
Out[5]: [20, 92, 130]
```

Comment: Definitely like this solution more, like how the lambda is used creatively.

Comment: Very nice solution but how do I change my list 'b' to the lambda conditions?

Comment: @Reman I have converted all the conditions in list "b", into lambda functions, and stored them in the list "conditions".

Comment: @GaneshTata, yes I've seen it but I don't have the possibility to have lambda function in my list "b". I have a list 'b' as in question. I have to adapt them including lambda functions.. Using list comprehension? Something like this `conditions = ["x:x==" + a if a.isdigit() elif "x: x in " + a if "range" in a else "a: a " + a for a in b]`

Comment: found it: `["x:x==" + a if a.isdigit() else "x: x in " + a if "range" in a else "a: a " + a for a in b]`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you could change `b` to hold valid conditions (when concatinated with elements from `a`) as discussed in the comments above:

```
b = ["==2", "==5", "==20", "in range(50,100)", ">120"]
```

You could concatinate each element of `a` with these conditions and use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) to check if it evaluates to `True` or `False`. This, of course, can be done in a list comprehension:

```
result = [i for i in a if any(eval(str(i) + x) for x in b)]
```

Comment: Tnx, If you take `a = [3, 6, 20, 24, 36, 92, 130, 180, 182, 190]` and `b = ['==2', 'in range(150,200)', '<120', '180']` the output is wrong

Comment: `180` is a number, not a condition. The program concatenates the two strings and Python interprets everything with value as `True`. You can check this with `print(not(3180))`.

Comment: If I use above lists.. '130' is in result.

Answer (score 2):

*you want simple ,pythonic and easy to grasp forget the above ones*

```
a = [3, 6, 20, 24, 36, 92, 130]
[i for i in a if i==2 or i==5 or i==20 or i>120 or 50<=i<=100 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on previous answers, I think there could be 2 more ways.

```
#1
numbers = [3, 6, 20, 24, 36, 92, 130]
conditions = [
    lambda n: n == 2,
    lambda n: n == 5,
    lambda n: n == 20,
    lambda n: n in range(50, 100),
    lambda n: n > 120,
]
result = [num for num in numbers for condition in conditions if condition(num)]

#2
condition = lambda n: n in {2, 5, 20} or 50 <= n <= 100 or n > 120
result = list(filter(condition, numbers))
```

For a really big list, you should go with example #2 because it is more memory efficient and time complexity is linear instead of quadratic-like in #1